# Symfony2 command run cache:clear -e prod

Tags: symfony, command

I am trying to write symfony2 command that runs few other command.
But when I run

```
$this->getApplication()->find('cache:clear')->run(new ArrayInput(array(
    'command' => 'cache:clear',
    '-e' => 'prod'
)), $output);
$output->writeln('Done clearing cache prod!');
```

it it ignores '-e' => 'prod' parameters giving:

```
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
```

instead of:

```
Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `'command' => 'cache:clear',` since you are already running on that Command you have found from the Application, so you don't need to specify it again.

```
$this->getApplication()->find('cache:clear')->run(new ArrayInput(array(
    '-e' => 'prod'
)), $output);
```

Comment: It throws: [RuntimeException] Not enough arguments.

Comment: @sepikas_antanas hmm, that's weird, I need to look into this more. I would have expected it to work the same way as [CommandTester](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#testing-commands) does. An alternative might be use Symfony Process to execute the command.